# Publish .net core 3.1 api in Azure Devops publishes another web project

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops

I am having a weird issue when trying to publish my .NET Core 3.1 Web Api.
In my YAML file I have added this to publish my project:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
inputs:
command: 'publish'
projects: 'BITSolutions.InvoiceTool.Service\BITSolutions.InvoiceTool.Service.csproj'
arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
outputDir: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
```

Everytime I run my build pipeline using this task, the task is executing the following line:

```
"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" publish D:\a\1\s\BITSolutions.InvoiceTool.Web\BITSolutions.InvoiceTool.Web.csproj --configuration Release --output D:\a\1\a\BITSolutions.InvoiceTool.Web
```

It is publishing my Blazor Server project instead of my Service web api project as I stated in the task.

Any idea why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add logs?

Comment: Try to disable the option `Publish web projects` in the `dotnet publish` task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really a Blazor issue, more DevOps/YAML question.

The `DotNetCoreCLI@2` task has a `publishWebProjects` parameter which defaults to `true` if not specified.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops

Add the line

```
  publishWebProjects: false
```

to the task, that should fix it.